# Insert html and php within php

Tags: php, html, insert

I have this line of code

```
<?php if ( current_theme_supports( 'breadcrumb-trail' ) ) breadcrumb_trail( array( 'container' => 'nav', 'separator' => '>', 'before' => __( 'You are here:', 'chun' ) ) ); ?>
```

How do I insert the following code to replace the 'You are here' part?

```
 <a href="http://myblog.com"><img src="http://myblog/img/mini-gek.gif" alt="Home" title="Home"></a>             
        <span class="issue-num">The Itinerant &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo do_shortcode("[issuem_issue_title]"); ?>
                </span>
```

I'm unsure how to break it up correctly.

Comment: You are using a framework. Which one?

Comment: He is using wordpress

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php if ( current_theme_supports( 'breadcrumb-trail' ) ) breadcrumb_trail( array( 'container' => 'nav', 'separator' => '>', 'before' => __( ' <a href="http://myblog.com"><img src="http://myblog/img/mini-gek.gif" alt="Home" title="Home"></a>             
    <span class="issue-num">The Itinerant &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;'.do_shortcode("[issuem_issue_title]").'
            </span>', 'chun' ) ) ); ?>
```

Is this maybe what you ment?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?php if ( current_theme_supports( 'breadcrumb-trail' ) ) breadcrumb_trail( array( 'container' => 'nav', 'separator' => '>', 'before' => '<a href="http://myblog.com"><img src="http://myblog/img/mini-gek.gif" alt="Home" title="Home"></a>             
<span class="issue-num">The Itinerant &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;'  .do_shortcode("[issuem_issue_title]") .'</span>'
 )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a variable to hold the text you want replaced ... like this:

```
$some_value = do_shortcode("[issuem_issue_title]"); 

$replace_with = <<< some_placeholder
<a href="http://myblog.com"><img src="http://myblog/img/mini-gek.gif" alt="Home" title="Home"></a>             
        <span class="issue-num">The Itinerant &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;$some_value
                </span>
some_placeholder;
```

And then use that variable instead of the phrase `You are here`

```
<?php if ( current_theme_supports( 'breadcrumb-trail' ) ) breadcrumb_trail( array( 'container' => 'nav', 'separator' => '>', 'before' => __( $replace_with, 'chun' ) ) ); ?>
```

---

Edit: just realized that I had `php` code inside the text, so I moved it outside to yet another variable.

Comment: It's good but a bit convoluted. I'm saving this to be used elsewhere though, thank you.

Comment: @demonboy glad to be of service somehow, and thanks to your comment I realized that I had php code inside the text area, so I moved it outside so it would at least run. So thank you also